# Building android app :I can sending data to database in localhost but not the same in online database

Tags: java, mysql, localhost, android-volley

I'm little confuse about what happen in my android app, because I don't understand why I can send data using my android app to localhost database and I can't do the same job in online database. The biggest problem is I can't find an error.

Notice: I use  volley=>(StringRequest) to send data to database

This is my class Myrequest to send data to database:

```java
public class MyRequest {

    private Context context;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    public MyRequest(Context context, RequestQueue queue) {
        this.context = context;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void register(final String nom, final String prenom,
                         final String naissance, final String telephone, final String email
            , final String fonction
            , final String commentaire, final String imagedata,
                         final RegistreCallback callback) {

        String url =
                "http://wided.epizy.com/index.php?controller=utilisateur&action=enregistrer";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST
                , url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                callback.onSuccess("inscription validée");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    callback.onError("Impossible de se connecter");
                } else if (error instanceof VolleyError) {

                    callback.onError("une erreur s'est produite");
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("nom", nom);
                map.put("prenom", prenom);
                map.put("naissance", naissance);
                map.put("telephone", telephone);
                map.put("email", email);
                map.put("fonction", fonction);
                map.put("commentaire", commentaire);
                map.put("image", imagedata);
                return map;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);
    }

    public interface RegistreCallback {
        void onSuccess(String message);

        void inputErrors(Map<String, String> errors);

        void onError(String message);
    }
}
```

The output log:

> 2019-09-08 21:33:34.448 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp I/System.out: Sun Sep 08 21:33:34 GMT+01:00 2019
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.449 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "8"
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at com.example.eventapp.Main2Activity$4.onClick(Main2Activity.java:227)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.450 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:34.456 14735-14908/com.example.eventapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
>   2019-09-08 21:33:35.305 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3a63de6
>   2019-09-08 21:33:35.820 14735-14764/com.example.eventapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe65ff7c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe65b1d00)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:36.082 14735-14764/com.example.eventapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe65ff7c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe65b1d00)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:36.184 14735-14764/com.example.eventapp I/chatty: uid=10087(com.example.eventapp) RenderThread identical 1 line
>   2019-09-08 21:33:36.222 14735-14764/com.example.eventapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe65ff7c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe65b1d00)
>   2019-09-08 21:33:36.525 14735-14735/com.example.eventapp D/AutofillManager: onActivityFinishing(): calling cancelLocked()
>   2019-09-08 21:33:37.377 14735-14764/com.example.eventapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe65ff7c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe65b1d00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the free service from the infinityfree site.

infinityfree refuses to accept data from android application.

detail
https://infinityfree.net/support/javascript-error-using-api-or-mobile-android-app/

Comment: you are absolutely right , thanks for your answer , can you tell me a free WebHost that provide me sending data with mobile app .

Comment: 000webhost is happening but not very slow, efficient.

1. I recommend you to buy a package at webkur.com.tr.
https://www.webkur.com.tr/hosting

2. I suggest you use heroku + github + free mysql.
This is my suggestion for free Mysql. https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/

Happy Days.